# Open popup from service

Tags: c#, service

I have created a windows service that checks a new release of an application. And if there is a new release then it will show an alert or message to the user saying that "A new release is available. Do you want to install it?".

My service is ready but I am not able to show this message to the user from Windows Service.

Comment: Services shouldn't have any UI, so it usualy means creating a user mode app, that communicates with the service, you can place it in the taskbar to pop your toast or what ever it is you want... anyway way too broad

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: you cannot.

Longer version: a few years ago the use of highly privileged processes (services showing UI) opened up vulnerabilities where user processes could be elevated to gain those higher privileges. Therefore the capability was blocked.

Instead you need a completely separate user process to provide the UI and some form of inter-process communication (like a named pipe with a carefully chosen ACL) to connect to the service. This also allows you to handle the case where no one (via make the connection work across the network) or multiple users are logged in (and none on the console).